# Why is the browser not recognising my Javascript commands

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to learn Javascript and trying to include prompts and alerts into my HTML script.

Please can anyone note anything wrong with the codes below?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="stalker.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <h1>test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the javascript code:

```
prompt(“what is your first name?”);
var fname = prompt(“what is your first name?”);

prompt(“what is your last name?”)
var lname = prompt(“what is your last name?”);

prompt(“what is your age?”);
var age = prompt(“what is your age?”)
```

Can anyone please tell me why when I run it in the browser, the prompts do not run?

Comment: Is the file definitely loading? Do you see any warnings or errors in the console?

Comment: You should open the browser's console (usually with F12), and check the error messages you see there. One thing that is not correct are the curly quotes. That is a syntax error.

Comment: does your javascript file and html belongs to same directory ?

Comment: You don't want to be using these kind of quotes in code `“` - use these instead: `"`

Comment: i dont think ur js is loading, consolelog and check

Answer (score 2):

I copy Pasted your java script code in my file and checked it. Looks like you have double quotation Marks in your code instead of double quotes.

Below code worked for me.

```
var fname = prompt("what is your first name?");

prompt("what is your last name?")
var lname = prompt("what is your last name?");

prompt("what is your age?");
var age = prompt("what is your age?")
```

Also you can click on F12 or open console to look at the errors when you think your js code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Use " what is your first name? "

```
  var fname = prompt("what is your first name?");

  prompt("what is your last name?")
  var lname = prompt("what is your last name?");

  prompt("what is your age?");
  var age = prompt("what is your age?")
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked immediately. So is the issue that I should set the variable first and assign the prompt the variable?

Comment: @ZenMournster It was syntactical issues.

Answer (score 0):

**Just for you ack:** HTML tag is wrong and “ should be `"` .

```js
  var fname = prompt("what is your first name?");
  console.log("name: "+ fname)
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>

</head>
<body>
  <h1>test</h1>

</body>
</html>
```